# Formatting PHP Array from JSON Object in HTML

Tags: php, arrays, json, twitch

How can I format the following output (Using cURL in PHP to parse a json object to an array and display properly formatted text in HTML)

```
function curlTwitch() {

  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/?game=Overwatch");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array (
    'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json',
    'Client-ID: x8j9dhw66qkgbsw67bfwtos4hyfeww'
  ));


$result = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump( json_decode($result, true) );

//echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

}
```

My current output fills the page in an unreadable format and is shown as something like:

```
array(2) { ["_total"]=> int(872) ["streams"]=> array(25) { [0]=> array(14) { 
["_id"]=> int(30799425120) ["game"]=> string(9) "Overwatch" 
["broadcast_platform"]=> string(4) "live" ["community_id"]=> string(0) "" 
["community_ids"]=> array(0) { } ["viewers"]=> int(6104) ["video_height"]=> 
int(900) ["average_fps"]=> int(60) ["delay"]=> int(0) ["created_at"]
```

Comment: can you show your desired html code layout?

Comment: I ultimately want to be able to parse the output and display each node separately in the final result. 

As of current, I just want to see the structure. Something akin to: https://imgur.com/a/oKC6qzu

Comment: well, if you save it to a new var, ie `$result = json_decode($result, true);`, then you can access each node like -> `$result['streams'][0]['game'];` / `$result['streams'][0]['broadcast_platform'];`

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful and I will keep in mind! However, how can I go about seeing/outputting the actual structure in a read-able format here so that I can see all of the nodes that I'd possibly like to parse?

Comment: you can use `<pre>` and `print_r()` -> `$results = json_decode($result, true); echo "<pre>".print_r($results, 1). "</pre>";`.

Comment: This works - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're outputting to HTML, try adding a `<pre>` tag before the output:

```
<pre><?= json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); ?></pre>
```

This should produce the following output:

```
{
    "_total": 872,
    "streams": [
        {
            "_id": 30799425120,
            "game": "Overwatch",
            "broadcast_platform": "live",
            "community_id": '',
            "community_ids": [],
            "viewers": 6104,
            "video_height": 900,
            "average_fps": 60,
            "delay": 0,
            "created_at": '...'
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason this gave me output of everything on one line.

Comment: Can you please make a screenshot? Otherwise it's not clear, really :/